# c3js, X Axis crushed and badly formated

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

Currently I am playing arround with this Example:
http://c3js.org/samples/axes_x_tick_culling.html

But the issue is, when you add like 3-4x the Ammount of Data, the X values get crushed and badly formated. How can I fix this any idea?

See here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzrTR.png

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Width is working fine for me, take a look [X axis with tripple digit numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nw4pD.png)

[enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/michaelrodov/3vL6bky0/2/)

```
var chart = c3.generate({
data: {
    columns: [
        ['sq', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250, 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250, 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250,30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250, 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250, 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250,30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250, 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250, 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250,30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250, 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250, 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250,30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250, 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250, 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250,30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250, 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250, 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250,30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250, 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250, 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250]
```

]

```
},
axis: {
    x: {
        type: 'category',
        tick: {
        width: 22,
            culling: {
                max: 7 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Here you go,
you need to add the tick.width parameter.
It's not documented yet (we're working on it)

```js
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
                        ['sq', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 11,11,11,11,111,11,11,11,22,22,22,22,22,223,43,32,14,250, 30,31, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250, 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250]]
        
    },
    axis: {
        x: {
            type: 'category',
            tick: {
                culling: true,
                width: 11
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.11/c3.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.11/c3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart">
</div>
```

```
var chart = c3.generate({
data: {
    columns: [
                    ['sq', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 11,11,11,11,111,11,11,11,22,22,22,22,22,223,43,32,14,250, 30,31, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250, 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250]]

},
axis: {
    x: {
        type: 'category',
        tick: {
            culling: true,
            width: 11
        }
    }
}
```

});

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/michaelrodov/6enygkbx/)

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the Post. Eh, the Numers still get stacked up If i have more values added, thats not a fix for it. Actually better would be to Display the X Avis completely outside of the Graph like that: http://i.imgur.com/AWgYzZj.png

Comment: whats the length of the numbers? I used 3 digit number s and it went fine